# Laravel Carbon get start + end of current week

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, php-carbon

I am working with Laravel 4 on a tool to publish/schedule restaurant menus on facebook.
For this I need a date selector for the current week, starting always on monday and ending always on sunday.

[Wireframe for restaurant menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leGH5.png)

I'have played around with the examples http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-getters but without success.

Any idea?

Answer (score 62):

This is pretty simple with Carbon Library. Here is the code example:

```
$now = Carbon::now();
$weekStartDate = $now->startOfWeek()->format('Y-m-d H:i');
$weekEndDate = $now->endOfWeek()->format('Y-m-d H:i');
```

Even you have the option to change start and end day of the week. It is like this,

```
$start = $now->startOfWeek(Carbon::TUESDAY);
$end = $now->endOfWeek(Carbon::MONDAY);
```

Source: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-getters

Comment: this will set both variables to the end of the week, as `->startOfWeek` will change the variable, not make clone of it

Comment: To avoid making a clone, use ->copy()

Comment: Better to use the interface for Carbon constants:
`CarbonInterface::MONDAY`

Answer (score 8):

The best way is using jquery plugin

> http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

In your view.blade.php make input field

```
<input type="text" id="in">
```

In your script file select this input and set date range

```
<script>
        $("#in").datepicker({
            minDate: new Date("{{Carbon\Carbon::now()->startOfWeek()->format('Y/m/d')}}"),
            maxDate: new Date("{{Carbon\Carbon::now()->endOfWeek()->format('Y/m/d')}}")
        });
</script>
```

This should be look like this

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXZkT.jpg

Answer (score 6):

Please note, you will need to use CarbonImmutable if you want the Start Date to remain the beginning of the week.  (Also it isn't "Laravel Carbon" it is just Carbon)

```
$now = CarbonImmutable::now();
$weekStartDate = $now->startOfWeek();
$weekEndDate = $now->endOfWeek();
```

Comment: Thank you. I was totally perplexed as to why my start date was being altered by calling `endOfWeek()` on the original date instance. Now I get it.

Answer (score 5):

This gives you the start of the week (monday) until the end of the week (sunday).
No idea whether this is a setting on the server. (Some people put the initial week on Sunday)

```
private $start;
private $end;

public function setWeekPeriod($weeknumber)
{
    $week_start = (new DateTime())->setISODate(date("Y"),$weeknumber)->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    $this->start = Carbon::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", $week_start);
    $this->start->hour(0)->minute(0)->second(0);
    $this->end = $this->start->copy()->endOfWeek();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Worked fine for me.

```
$now = now();
$weekStartDate = $now->copy()->startOfWeek()->format('Y-m-d');
$weekEndDate = $now->copy()->endOfWeek()->format('Y-m-d');
```